# HighChart Columnrange to combine with a LINE?

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

With Highchart, i have a `columnrange` chart and i made it vertical columns.
Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/zYKCp/

There how can i put a HORIZONTAL LINE cutting through the column bars, please?

```
         __
   __    | |
   | |   | |   __
   | |   | |   | |
---------------------
   | |   | |   | |
   ---   | |   | |
         | |   ---
         ---
```

To put a horizontal LINE like that.
Thanks much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I got it already by ..

1. Removing the `chart: {type: 'columnrange'},`
2. Putting `type: 'column',.......` in Serie for the Bars.
3. Add one more type as `type: 'spline',.......` for the Line.

Something like what i do here --> [jsFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Xr3up/)